# Why won't wget work with cron?

Tags: terminal, script, bash, command-line

I've been using the [bashpodder script](http://lincgeek.org/bashpodder/) recently, and while the script works beautifully when I use it in the command line, the crontab I created for it doesn't work at all. It fails when it has to use wget. I downloaded the most recent OS X binaries for wget, but the script still fails, and I get a log with an error that reads thus:

```
Users/username/Downloads/audio/podcasts/bashpodder.shell: line 73: wget: command not found
```

Lines 71-75 read like this:

```
if ! grep "$url" podcast.log > /dev/null
      then
         wget -t 10 -U BashPodder -c -q -O $datadir/$(echo "$url"  | awk -F'/' {'print $NF'}  |  awk -F'='         {'print $NF'} | awk -F'?' {'print $1'}) "$url"
         let "show += 1"
    fi
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 11):

`wget` isn't in the default path used by `cron`. Give it the `/full/path/to/wget` and it should work.

Comment: Set PATH in the shell file also wroks.